# phonegap - postMessage - origin security

Tags: cordova, security, postmessage

How do you check the origin for a postMessage sent from a PhoneGap app?

I set up an iframe in PhoneGap:

```
<iframe id="receiver" src="http://example.com/receiver.html" width="90" height="90"></iframe>
```

In PhoneGap javascript, send a message:

```
var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
receiver.postMessage('from phonegap app', 'http://example.com');
```

In receiver.html, some javascript to receive the message:

```
function receiveMessage(e) { alert(e.data) }
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
```

For security, in `function receiveMessage` I should check the origin:

```
function receiveMessage(e) { 
    if (e.origin !== "something here")
        return;
    else
        alert(e.data);
```

But since the message came from a PhoneGap app, origin is always just `file://`. 
Is checking for `file://` acceptable for security? Or is there some other value I should use?

In case it matters, I have `<access origin="http://example.com" />` in the app's config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is to send data (from Cordova app to iframe) as an object, and set password inside this object.
My implementation would be:

To send message:

```
function sendMessage() {
var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
var data={
pw: ‘mypassword’,
value1: ‘first value’,
value2:1234
};
receiver.postMessage(data, 'http://example.com');
};
```

To receive message in iframe:

```
function receiveMessage(e) { 
   if (e.data.pw !== ‘mypassword’){
        alert(wrong password)    //(or return)
}
    else{
alert(e.data.value1+e.data.value2)
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From PhoneGap (or Cordova) you could use an InAppBrowser to load external content, which has support to inject CSS and [JavaScript](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserexecutescript) (with result callback) but only from the app towards loaded / external site, which is exactly what you need.

```js
var browser = window.open('https://example.net', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no,hidden=yes');

browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
    browser.executeScript({
        code: "localStorage.getItem('key_from_external_site_localStorage')", // or file: 'appLocalInjectScript.js',
        function( values ) {
            var value = values[ 0 ];

            navigator.notification.alert('Value received: ' + value, null, 'Success');
        }
    })
})
```

```